# How to wirelessly upload an arduino uno using the hc-08 bluetooth module?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-uno, wireless

If it is even possible, I would like to know how to wirelessly upload a sketch from my windows 10 laptop to my arduino uno using the HC-08 bluetooth module. I already built the project and did the wiring and I am already using the Bluetooth module for sending data to my iPhone. I am in high school so I do not know a lot about electronics but I have been working with the arduino for 3 months and  I have been programming for 2 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems like you can't upload a new sketch to the Arduino using only the HC-08 Bluetooth module without altering the boot loader or using additional hardware, because you would need to reset the Arduino at the right time.

However, I suggest you to have a look at the [official Arduino forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=399114.0) for further information.